# Change/cycle through images using Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I'm following TechFunda's code on changing an image on a button click. Here is the code:

http://techfunda.com/howto/444/changing-of-images

```
<h1>Changing the Image</h1>
    <img src="waterbottel.gif" id="myImage" width="100" height="150">
    <input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value="Change" />
    <p>Click on the "Change" button to convert waterbottle<br />
        into Softdrink bottle</p>

    <script>
        function changeImage() {
            var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
            if (image.src.match("colorbottel")) {
                image.src = "waterbottel.gif";
            }
            else {
                image.src = "colorbottel.gif";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

It goes from one image to the second, then back to the first.

How would I go about adding another image to be in the cycle? (e.g. first image > second image > third image > back to first)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array of `src`s instead, and increment an index through the array:

```
const srcs = ['foo.png', 'bar.png', 'baz.png'];
let i = 0;
function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  i = (i + 1) % srcs.length;
  image.src = srcs[i];
}
```

Live demo:

```js
const srcs = ['https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/49196f761a0b00f0ee42e3e4e6bad2f0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1', 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/34932d3e923ffad9a4a1423e30b1d9fc?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1'];
let i = 0;

function changeImage() {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  i = (i + 1) % srcs.length;
  image.src = srcs[i];
}
```

```html
<h1>Changing the Image</h1>
<img src="waterbottel.gif" id="myImage" width="100" height="150">
<input type="button" onclick="changeImage()" value="Change" />
<p>Click on the "Change" button to convert waterbottle<br /> into Softdrink bottle</p>
```

Comment: Can you put your example into a JSfiddle, or have the rest of the code involved in your message so I can run it? The code allows it to go to the next image, but once it reaches the last, it won't go back to the first image again.

Comment: Are you sure you added the `% srcs.length`? That will have `i` loop around back to 0 after the final image is reached

Comment: I must have done something weird with my code somewhere initially. It works now! Thank you so very much.

Comment: What do I do with the script when I have multiple buttons? One button changes an image, while another button changes a different image (unrelated to the first button)?

Comment: Have a different array (and a different image selector) for each image / button

Comment: May I have an example for that as well?

Comment: Just copy the code again, but use different variable names everywhere. Eg `const srcs2 = ['foo.png', 'bar.png', 'baz.png'];
let i2 = 0;
function changeImage2() {
  var image2 = document.getElementById('myImage2');
  i2 = (i2 + 1) % srcs2.length;
  image2.src = srcs[i2];
}` and replace the `src`s in the array as well. Could also be done less repetitively

Comment: Do I need to separate the two different Javascript codes in some way?

Comment: No, no problem putting them in the same file

Comment: I replaced the srcs for the second, but the second button changes the second srcs to the first array's srcs. Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/Jonjei/s04nL97e/13/

Comment: Need to change `image2.src = srcs[i2];` to `image2.src = srcs2[i2];`, all the variable names should be different, using this approach

Comment: Changed, and everything's working now and looks amazing. Thanks so much for all your help!